# Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in` Sidebar`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

I use the react sidebar library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidebar.
I have an error:

> VM73295 checkPropTypes.js: 20 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop
>   `children` is marked as required in`Sidebar`, but its value is
>   `undefined`.

```
<Sidebar
  sidebar={ 
    <div className="addPeopleNav">
      <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>'mmmmm'</Form.Label>

      </Form.Group>
    </div>
  }
  open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
  onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
  styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white", width: "180px", height: '400px'} }}
  pullRight={false}
  className="sidebar"
> 
</Sidebar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sidebar` must have a `children`. Any element will work

```
<Sidebar
  sidebar={ 
    <div className="addPeopleNav">
      <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>'mmmmm'</Form.Label>

      </Form.Group>
    </div>
  }
  open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
  onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
  styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white", width: "180px", height: '400px'} }}
  pullRight={false}
  className="sidebar"
> 
    <div />
</Sidebar>
```